# Bitmap.Save creates empty file

Tags: c#, bitmap, xna, drawing

It started with this: [Application runs out of memory while saving textures to PNG files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066281/application-runs-out-of-memory-while-saving-textures-to-png-files/57098231#57098231)

Since there was no solution and the SaveAsPng method just kept eating memory, I went with making my own Png saver algorithm. Now, if at all possible, I would happily avoid learning the exact specifications of the PNG format and just use an existing algorithm for properly encoding my color data, so I researched and found the System.Drawing library, and the Bitmap.Save() method contained within.

I wrote up the png saving code, got it running, it's creating files. Which are all empty. It gives me properly formatted (at least Photoshop didn't complain about opening them) png files with big, fat 0-es where the color data is supposed to be.

I have tested if the data I'm extracting from the XNA texture is correct. It is. I tested to see if the data in the Bitmap object is correct. It is. So I'm back to where I started: I set everything up and the one method I'm using to do the actual saving of the data screws me over.

```cs
void savePng(Texture2D tex, string path)
{
    Color[] colorData = new Color[tex.Width * tex.Height];
    tex.GetData(colorData);

    //Console.WriteLine(colorData[12810].ToString());

    byte[] rawData = new byte[4 * colorData.Length];

    for (int i=0; i<rawData.Length; i++)
        {
        switch (i%4)
            {
            case 0:
                rawData[i] = colorData[i/4].A;
            break;

            case 1:
                rawData[i] = colorData[i/4].R;
            break;

            case 2:
                rawData[i] = colorData[i/4].G;
            break;

            case 3:
                rawData[i] = colorData[i/4].B;
            break;
            }
        }

    IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(rawData.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(rawData, 0, pointer, rawData.Length);

    using (System.Drawing.Bitmap b = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(tex.Width, tex.Height, tex.Width * 4, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb, pointer))
        {
        //Console.WriteLine(b.GetPixel(10, 10).ToString());
        b.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pointer);
}
```

At least it's not leaking memory like the Titanic. Can anybody please explain the empty files? Please?

Comment: Your code (using a random color array) works fine here so your Texture2D may be off.

Comment: Can you try `tex.GetData<Color>(colorData);`

Comment: That's very interesting. I'll check some things, thank you for actually taking the time and compiling and running this to test. Much appreciated.

Comment: The thing is 1, I'm actually also drawing the texture (RenderTarget2D really) to screen, it looks okay there. 2, You see the commented out console writes? Those were to see if the color of the pixel is both the same in the two objects and that it's non-zero. And I confirmed those.

Comment: Well, I don't do unity so I faked the data like this: `Bitmap tex = new Bitmap(150,150);
int max = tex.Width * tex.Height;
//Color[] colorData = new Color[tex.Width * tex.Height];
//tex.GetData(colorData);
Random rnd = new Random(9);
Color[] colorData = new Color[max];

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    colorData[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, rnd.Next(i%255), rnd.Next(223), 255- rnd.Next(222));
}`